# Mobile navbar horizontal scroll on Skrollr page

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, skrollr

My mobile navbar is position fixed at the bottom of the screen and overflows to the right. I want to be able to scroll this horizontally, however, skrollr seems to be capturing the scroll event and translating it into vertical scroll.

Once I disable skrollr, I can horizontally scroll the navbar.

I tried bringing the zindex of the navbar as high as possible, but skrollr still picks up the touch over it.

Is this possible at all?

EDIT:

thought to upload a sketch of what I want to achieve to make it more clear.

The overlay is position fixed, sitting at the bottom of the screen, z indexed above everything, with it's contents overflowing to the right:

```
white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;
```

On mobile, dragging the overlay starts scrolling the whole page, and the overlay is not scrolling left-right. If I use the mouse horizontal wheel, it does scroll, but not on touch.

[image]

Comment: share your code

Comment: here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozxgKy) (but you need to view this is a mobile emulator to be able to see the problem, as you can scroll the overlay with normal scroll - not with touch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to fixed this by stopping propagation on `touchmove`, `touchstart` and `touchend` events, on the overlay element:

`$overlay.on('touchmove touchstart touchend', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});`

this broke tapping on any links that are inside the overlay, but adding a dummy listener to them fixed it:

`$overlayLinks.on('touchmove touchstart touchend', function() {
    return true;
});`